# PHP page login with two folders

Tags: php, mysql

I have page login.php :

```
<?php 

include '../f-connect.php';

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
     extract($_POST);
     $password = sha1($password);
     $sql = "SELECT u.*, r.* FROM users as u INNER JOIN roles AS r ON r.id_roles = u.roles_id WHERE u.login = '$login' AND u.password = '$password' AND r.name  = 'provider'";
     $req = $db->prepare($sql);
     $req->execute();
    if($req->rowCount() > 0){
        $data = $req->fetch();
        $_SESSION['Auth']= array(
            'id_user' => $data['id_user'],
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'login' => $data['login'],
            'password' => $data['password'],
            'roles_id' => $data['roles_id'],
            'id_roles' => $data['id_roles'],
            'name' => $data['name'],

        );




            $_SESSION['flash']['success'] = "You are now connected";
        header("Location:../Provider/profilProvider.php");
    }else{
        echo '<div class ="alert alert-warning">Login or password incorrect</div>';
    }

}elseif(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
     extract($_POST);
     $password = sha1($password);
     $sql = "SELECT u.*, r.* FROM users as u INNER JOIN roles AS r ON r.id_roles = u.roles_id WHERE u.login = '$login' AND u.password = '$password' AND r.name  = 'customer'";
     $req = $db->prepare($sql);
     $req->execute();
    if($req->rowCount() > 0){
        $data = $req->fetch();
        $_SESSION['Auth']= array(
            'id_user' => $data['id_user'],
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'login' => $data['login'],
            'password' => $data['password'],
            'roles_id' => $data['roles_id'],
            'id_roles' => $data['id_roles'],
            'name' => $data['name'],

        );


            $_SESSION['flash']['success'] = "You are now connected";
        header("Location:../customer/profilCustomer.php");
    }else{
        echo '<div class ="alert alert-warning">Login or password incorrect</div>';
    }

}
?>
```

And i have two folders that contain:

```
folder one : 
provider : 
   ->profilProvider.php
   ->listProviders.php
   ->addProvider.php
   ->updateProvider.php



folder two : 
   customer : 
    ->profilCustomer.php
    ->listCustomers.php
    ->addCustomer.php
    ->updateCustomer.php
```

And i have table users :

```
 - id_user : int 
 - firstname :varchar(100) 
 - lastname : varchar(100) 
 - login : varchar(100) 
 - password : varchar(100) 
 - roles_id : int
```

And table roles :

```
- id_roles : int
- name : varchar(100)  ['provider', 'costumer']
```

when I would enter the login and password I want to redirect to one of these two folders

for example :

- if the  role equal provider I would go to the profilProvider.php
  page in the provider folder
- if the  role equal costumer I would go to the profilCostumer.php
  page in the costumer folder

**But not direct me in associated folders**

Comment: Where is your login.php page Outside the folder one & folder two or inside some other folder in your project. :)

Comment: @NareshKumar.P ;  login.php is in another folder.

Comment: Can you mention up the folder structure where you have the login.php file in your project since it would be very useful to figure out our Error :)

Comment: for example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/zakiovi/og7x57x2/

Answer (score 0):

> You have to provide the exact path to the file as per the header location is considered based on the project structure.

```
My Project - (Main Folder) 
login.php 
provider - (Sub Folder One)
->profilProvider.php    
->listProviders.php     
->addProvider.php       
->updateProvider.php 
customer - (Sub Folder Two)     
->profilCustomer.php    
->listCustomers.php    
->addCustomer.php   
->updateCustomer.php
```

The header location what you have given in the both the conditions will cause you an error since your path to the folder/directory seems incorrect.

**Reason:**

Your project structure looks like the above one. My doubt is only with the **include '../f-connect.php';** since the path provided here seems to be incorrect with your project structure.

If this seems correct then you have to replace the header location alone in your code as i suggest now.

> Note: Since "../" will **go back one directory from the Current working folder**. As per you jsfiddle explanation you have your login.php file inside the project folder. and hence you have to change the header location alone.

Solution for needing ob_start() in your project.

> If you find header already sent Error while redirection you can use **ob_start()** after the **include '../f-connect.php'** line.

Replaced Code:

```
<?php
// Database Connectivity
include '../f-connect.php';
// Checking condition based on the form Submission
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
     extract($_POST);
     $password = sha1($password);
     $sql = "SELECT u.*, r.* FROM users as u INNER JOIN roles AS r ON r.id_roles = u.roles_id WHERE u.login = '$login' AND u.password = '$password' AND r.name  = 'provider'";
     $req = $db->prepare($sql);
     $req->execute();
    if($req->rowCount() > 0){
        $data = $req->fetch();
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['Auth']= array(
            'id_user' => $data['id_user'],
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'login' => $data['login'],
            'password' => $data['password'],
            'roles_id' => $data['roles_id'],
            'id_roles' => $data['id_roles'],
            'name' => $data['name'],

        );
        $_SESSION['flash']['success'] = "You are now connected";
        // This header Location will provide you an error 
        // since "../" will go back one directory from the Current working folder.
        // As per you jsfiddel explanation you have your login.php file inside the project folder.
        //header("Location:../Provider/profilProvider.php");
        header("Location: provider/profilProvider.php");
        }else{
        echo '<div class ="alert alert-warning">Login or password incorrect</div>';
        }

    }
    else if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
     extract($_POST);
     $password = sha1($password);
     $sql = "SELECT u.*, r.* FROM users as u INNER JOIN roles AS r ON r.id_roles = u.roles_id WHERE u.login = '$login' AND u.password = '$password' AND r.name  = 'customer'";
     $req = $db->prepare($sql);
     $req->execute();
    if($req->rowCount() > 0){
        $data = $req->fetch();
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['Auth']= array(
            'id_user' => $data['id_user'],
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'login' => $data['login'],
            'password' => $data['password'],
            'roles_id' => $data['roles_id'],
            'id_roles' => $data['id_roles'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
        );
        $_SESSION['flash']['success'] = "You are now connected";
        header("Location: customer/profilCustomer.php");
    }else{
        echo '<div class ="alert alert-warning">Login or password incorrect</div>';
    }
}
?>
```